# Measurement system with MATLAB real-time windows target and NI PCI boards

Tags: matlab

I'm setting up an experiment which employs MATLAB real-time windows target and NI PCI-6229 and carrier SC-2345 board while I'm wondering about the hardware's compatibility

It's given from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/products/rtwt/supported/results.html)  (MATLAB support page) that PCI-6229 is supported. However, in my setup, SC-2345 signal conditioning board is put between my PC and PCI-6229 board. Therefore, I'm afraid it won't work

Any relevant experience about similar system is a big help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link could provide you some useful information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268389/data-acquisition-toolbox-for-matlab

Have you tried the setup yet? What does it report?

Can be that the hardware board itself is not perfectly supported but I could see that sill worth of trying. With MATLAB's Data Acquisition Toolbox you can do several things.

If you get the drivers right with the SC-2345 board you could read the data and use some medium between the SC-board and MATLAB. Of course the real time solution may then suffer loss of speed but at least the data could be available.

In practice: The medium between MATLAB and SC-board could be a temporary file like .txt or something that SC-board writes and MATLAB reads in sequence.

Myself I have been using just LabView with its DAQ-systems.

Comment: since I also need to do some control later, it needs real-time feature. So far, there's not been a particular solution for this, I'm gonna have to try the setup anyway. But about the medium method, could you be a bit more specific? any specific guides on that?

Comment: ni forums shows something optimistic for my problem: "As for your current setup, when using accessories such as the SC-2345 with MATLAB, keep in mind that the accessory is transparent.  Therefore, you need to reference the physical channels on your DAQ device, not the actual SCC modules as you do in MAX.  For example, if your SCC-AI03 is in slot J1 you would reference physical channel AI0." hope this works out

Comment: I think you're on a good track. I also could have thought about referencing straightly to physical channel instead of the module. Because if you get the right drivers for the DAQ-devices and for the SCC so I think you can read data to your PC. Then the problem left is just that you have to find way to bring it to the software. This is a common problem in software development for measurement systems. One possible method is that you somehow read the data and save it to a temporary file which is read by MATLAB e.g. this is just one option though.